# Use SQL Server to query CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to query CosmosDB from SQL Server 2016 SSMS?  I'm currently querying CosmosDB using the DocumentDB ODBC driver via SSIS.  Users are now asking for the ability to query CosmosDB directly from SSMS through some sort of view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is, you can use Linked Servers. For more information, 
https://samtran.me/2017/10/07/linked-servers-for-azures-nosql-cosmosdb/

Comment: This link reaches a website that try with insistence to install an Edge extension (since I'm using Edge).

Comment: It's a dead link,  and really the contents of the page should have been included here.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio makes use of SqlClient underneath, which makes the main GUI only compatible with SQL Server databases. Using Linked Servers might not work yet either, since SQL Server doesn't support DocDB drivers.